# Having trouble with :dependent => :destroy and before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two models, an Account model (has_many :users) and a User model (belongs_to :account, :dependent => :destroy).

My User model has the following:

```
def protect_master_user
  unless User.find_all_by_account_id_and_is_master(self.account_id, true).count > 1
    false
  end
end
```

I'm trying to protect the master users from being deleted. How can I override this if the parent (Account) is deleted? I've tried :dependent => :destroy and :delete to no avail.

EDIT: fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this: has_many :users, :dependent => :delete_all, or with an additional custom callback in Accounts. The :delete_all method is simpler, but not advised, because it means that none of your other call backs will happen on the user record.

The correct solution is a custom before_destroy callback in Account, working in tandem with the callback in user.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users 

  before_destroy :destroy_users
  protected
    def destroy_users
      users.each do |user|
        u.account_id = nil
        u.destroy
      end
    end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account

  before_destroy :protect_master_user

  protected
    def protect_master_user
      unless account_id.nil? ||! master || 
        User.find_all_by_account_id_and_master(self.account_id, true).count > 1
        errors.add_to_base "Cannot remove master user."
        return false
      end
    end
end
```

If the account.id is nil we short circuit the unless and the destroy continues. Same goes for if the user is not a master user. Why do we need to check if there's more than one master user if the object being destroyed isn't a master user either?

Again, delete could be used in place of destroy. But it skips any *_destroy callbacks you have or will ahve in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this is not working for me. What you suggested makes sense, but I think User destroy is first. Any other ideas?

Comment: Weird. I thought I had it working yesterday. I've updated it to use a custom call back and described why a :dependent => :delete_all is no good.

Comment: Thanks, I had come up with the same solution but wasn't sure if deleting users from the Account model was the way to go. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same question and conundrum recently and found the best way to deal with this was to handle it in the controller as I really only care if a user is trying to delete the last Master user rather than if the system is doing it:

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def destroy  
       user = current_account.users.find(params[:id].to_i)
       if allow_removal_of_user?(user) && user.destroy
         redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User sucessfully deleted"
       else 
         flash[:error] = user.errors.empty? ? "Error" : user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
         render :edit
       end 
     end 

   private
     def allow_removal_of_user?(user)
       if user == current_user
         errors.add(:user_removal, "Can't delete yourself")
         false
       elsif user.only_user? || (user.master_users_for_account.count == 1 && user.master_role?)
         errors.add(:user_removal, "Can't delete last Master user")
         false
       else
         true
       end
     end
   end
```

Hope this helps somebody!